# Column Limit on Long Table

Tags: longtable

Is there a limit to the number of columns longtable can handle? I keep getting errors when I try to input seven columns. Code below:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{sample_data.csv}
    Col1,Col2,Col3,ColPct,Col5,Col6,Col7
    111,65,64,5\%,a,b,c
    112,30,5,6\%,a,b,c
    113,92,1,8.4\%,a,b,c
    114,47,19,20\%,a,b,c
    115,38,15,1\%,a,b,c
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csvsimple,longtable,booktabs}
\begin{document}

    \csvreader[
    longtable=lrrrr,
    table head=
    \toprule\bfseries Col1 &\bfseries Col2 & \bfseries Col3 & \bfseries ColPct & \bfseries Col5 & \bfseries Col6 & \bfseries Col7\\ 
    \midrule\endhead\bottomrule\endfoot,
    late after line=\\,
    before reading={\catcode`\#=12},after reading={\catcode`\#=6}
    ]{sample_data.csv}{1=\One,2=\Two, 3=\Three, 4=\Four, 5=\Five,6=\Six,7=\Seven}
    {\One & \Two & \Three & \Four & \Five & \Six & \Seven}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `\csvautolongtable` can handle 7 columns, it does not allow you to specify the column formats.  So I replaced the definition of autolongtable (which is implemented as a keyword).

I left out the `sample_data.csv` definition, since you already have the file.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csvsimple,longtable,booktabs}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\longtableformat}{|*{\csv@columncount}{l|}}% default
\csvset{autolongtable/.style={
    file=#1,
    after head=\csv@pretable\begin{longtable}{\longtableformat}\csv@tablehead,% replaced default column formats
    table head=\hline\csvlinetotablerow\\\hline\endhead\hline\endfoot,
    late after line=\\,
    late after last line=\csv@tablefoot\end{longtable}\csv@posttable,
    command=\csvlinetotablerow}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\def\longtableformat{lrrrccc}%
\csvautolongtable{sample_data.csv}

\end{document}
```